# Is it possible to set certain header files to be compiled under "Release" mode in Visual Studio with CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2019

Is it possible to set certain header files to be compiled under "Release" mode in Visual Studio with CMake?

**Scenario:**

The entire project is set up with CMake (not generating proj/sln files, pointing directly at the project's directory)

We are bringing in a header-only dependency via CMake that runs quite fast when ran in Release mode, however, it does not run as fast when ran in debug mode.

Is it possible to set this dependency to build in release mode while the rest of the application runs in Debug mode? If this is not possible are there any work arounds?

For reference I am using Visual Studio 2019 Community 16.1.6

Comment: ***it does not run as fast when ran in debug mode*** Debug mode can be 100 times slower than release. I have seen cases where an application took seconds in Release mode and over a day in debug mode.

Comment: ***Is it possible to set this dependency to build in release mode while the rest of the application runs in Debug mode?*** Most likely not. This would likely cause you to have the debug and release runtime CRT at the same time which would cause UB.

Comment: You don't compile header files.  It's the `.cpp` files that use the header files that would need their compilation options changing.

Comment: "You don't compile header files" - of course. I should of realized what i was asking before i posted this. I will need to look into other avenues of deploying the dependency. Thank you drescherlm, Jesper & Richard.

Comment: For anyone else that may stumble upon this, Richard is 100% right about header files not being compiled, however, i was able to get the speed I was looking for an still use the debugger by switching "Configuration Type" to "RelWithDebInfo" under CMakeSettings.json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posting comment to answer the question)*

For anyone else that may stumble upon this, Richard is 100% right about header files not being compiled, however, i was able to get the speed I was looking for an still use the debugger by switching "Configuration Type" to "RelWithDebInfo" under CMakeSettings.json.

Answer (score 0):

Well, header files are not compiled, only included.

So to disable a header in debug build, the `DEBUG` macro should be enough:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#include "problematic_header.h"
#endif
```

Of course, you'll also have to disable any functionality using declarations from this header.